# Maximum number of consoles that we can run at a time

Tags: c#

Two questions:

1. Just wondering if there is a limit on the maximum number of consoles that we can spawn.
2. We have a scenario where we would like to downolad a bunch of files on the internet.
   While we can use threads for downolading each file but as i have learnt there is a limit of 2 threads for downloading we are thinking of spawning multiple consoles and create threads internally and download multiple files at a time.

Just wondering what others think.
Thanks

Comment: Whre did you get the limit from? And why do you think multiple consoles will help you get around this? (note: could be a server side limit, in which case your consoles achieve nothing).

Comment: Can provide the source from where you *learnt there is a limit of 2 threads for downloading*?

Comment: Even if you could spawn infinite consoles and download threads, keep in mind that you're still limited by your bandwidth. So it's not worth the trouble *if* you've already maxed out your download speed.

Comment: I'd guess the 'two threads for downloading' thing is the traditional browser restriction - although the limits are larger than that now in modern browsers and don't apply to your own code anyway.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298059/download-files-from-net-using-threading-or-not

Answer (score 4):

The number of simultaneous HTTP connections you can make to the same server can be changed in the [`<connectionManager>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) element of app.config. This would be a *far* better solution than trying to work round it via spawning... although you should still limit yourself sensibly.

For example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <!-- Increase the number of concurrent connections per server to 8. -->
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "8" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Also note that this is on a *per target address* basis... if you're trying to download from 20 different sites, you won't hit the limit anyway (although you might run out of bandwidth).

Answer (score 4):

Although there is a theoretical limit of the number of consoles / processes you can have open based on the maximum number of handles etc... it is extremely high and you are unlikely to reach it.

Note that you can in fact increase the number of allowed connections - it is simply set to 2 by default:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = myLimit;
```

This [blog article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mflasko/connection-groups-and-connection-limits) might also help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the WebClient class to override the connection limit on the service point.  This will negate the need to spawn multiple instances of your application:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient 
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 50;
        return (WebRequest)req;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends basically on your amount of RAM ;)

Answer (score -1):

For one, I think console is *just another app* for the OS, so it is really limited by your memory(RAM) limit.